# Angular: click an anchor tag element on an independent page

Tags: angular, click, anchor

I know that anchor tags in HTML can have direct links. Is it possible to simulate click event on such anchor tag on another page from Angular typescript code. In my scenario the anchor tag is on a page with localhost:8002 path.

What I have tried so far is

```
 @ViewChild('myDiv') myDiv: ElementRef<HTMLElement>;

   triggerFalseClick() {
    let el: HTMLElement = this.myDiv.nativeElement;
    el.click();
   }
```

and call the function on an internal event

in the template, I have

```
<a href = "http://localhost:8002/index2 #subE" #myDiv></a>
```

and the file that is running on http://localhost:8002/index2 is

```
<a name = "subE" id = "subE" href="/button/<two>" class="button" style="display: inline-block;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
</a>
```

Please help!

Comment: When you say "page", do you mean another component route in your app, or a completely different website?  If its the latter, no (unless its also your app and you can have some sort of web socket messaging protocol to communicate between user sessions).

Comment: Its a separate (Flask based) page on another port